# Group By An XPATH Is Not Using the Index - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, xpath

I have PostgreSQL and a database, inside the database I have a table that has a structure similar to the following:

```
ID (uuid) | User (xml) | Details (xml)
```

I want to perform a `group by` operation using an XPATH on both the User and Details column. So i created two indexes as the following:

```
create index idx_detail1
on mytable
using gin(cast(xpath('//Details/Detail/[@Name="Detail1"]', "Details") as text[]))

create index idx_user
on mytable
using gin(cast(xpath('//UserId/@Value', "User") as text[]))
```

Then, i do my `select` statement as the following:

```
select (cast(xpath('//UserId/@Value', "User") as text[]))[1], (cast(xpath('//Details/Detail/[@Name="Detail1"]', "Details") as text[]))[1], count(*)
from mytable
group by (cast(xpath('//UserId/@Value', "User") as text[]))[1], (cast(xpath('//Details/Detail/[@Name="Detail1"]', "Details") as text[]))[1]
```

The problem is that Postgres is not using the indexes i created and insists on performing a sequential scan on the table instead of using the indexes.

How can i make Postgres use the indexes for the `group by` operation?

Comment: Create regular (btree) index on `(cast(xpath('//UserId/@Value', "User") as text[]))[1]`. `order by`/`group by` uses `=, <, >` set of operators. But [`gin` index supports `&&, <@, =, @>` operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) (note that the equality operator here is applied to the whole indexed value, not to the part of it)